# Как разбить string-текст на массив слов в C#?

Tags: c#, массивы, строки

Строку нужно разбить на слова и записать их в массив  string[].

Comment: [string.Split(/* перечень разделителей */)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) не подхидит?

Comment: если не нравится string.Split можете разделить регуляркой  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex, там тоже есть Split (что б запятые с пробелами соидинялись).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Используем String.Split()

```
string[] mystring = str.Split(',');
```

Также можно использовать массив разделителей, более детально тут:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: можно использовать как разделитель пробел ?

Comment: Конечно, String.Split(" ")